# Parsing DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

If I have an xml file as follows,

```
<a> <b></b> <d> <c></c> </d></a>
```

I want to be able to break this down into three xml as follows,

```
<a> <b></b> <d></d> </a>

<c></c>

<a> <d></d> </a>
```

Is this possible using DOM?

Comment: what is the challenge in terms of code?

Comment: I looked up, there doesnt seem to be an easy way to achieve this

Comment: Also, the xml structure is unknown to us

Comment: How can u parse an xml and split of unknown structure? You need to know the schema..

Comment: The idea is, if we have element <c></c>, we need to break it into 3 xmls, otherwise leave it the way it is.

Comment: How about `<a> <b></b> <d> <c> <x></x> </c> </d></a>`?

Comment: No there will be no children for <c>

Comment: Can you use temporary files for this?

Comment: preferably no. but if u have a solution with temporary files, it may be helpful.

Comment: How about `<a> <b> <c> </c> </b> <d> <c>  </c> </d></a>`?

Comment: That will need to be     <a> <b> </b></a>, <c></c>, <d></d>, <c></c>, <d></d><a></a>

Comment: Your last comment contains more than 3 XMLs (the last one is even malformed XML). What exactly are your requirements? It is not clear from the question how the transformation should be done.

Comment: Instead of giving us an example and hoping that we can guess your requirements, it would be more useful to tell us the requirements. And of course the schema definition, which tags can be missing, which tags can be present multiple times etc.

Comment: Maybe this simple algorithm? Start parsing and keep a list of opened tags, when you encounter c, then you close all open tags and create an XML, then you create an XML for c (which seems to be redundant, it is just acting as delimiter and always the same), open the closed tags again and continue parsing...

Answer (score 6):

Try using VTD parser (requires ximpleware jar)..

given ..

```
<a> <b></b> <d> <c></c> </d></a>
```

the below code will generate four files (one for temp use), out of which three will have the required output.

```
<a> <b></b> <d></d> </a>

<c></c>

<a> <d></d> </a>
```

NOTE : this can be modified and implemented in a better way but the basic idea is given.

```
 // bunch of imports
public class vtd {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ModifyException, NavException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, TranscodeException {

    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen(); // Instantiate VTDGen
    XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(); //Instantiate XMLModifier
    XMLModifier xm1 = new XMLModifier();
    XMLModifier xm2 = new XMLModifier();
    //parse the main file
    vg.parseFile("e://test.xml", true);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);
    vn.toElement(VTDNav.NS);
    // check if the file has a node <c>
    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "c")) {

        if (vg.parseFile("e://test.xml", false)) {
            vn = vg.getNav(); // instantiate navigation opject
            xm.bind(vn);
            xm1.bind(vn);
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);
            if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NS, "d")) {
                long l = vn.getContentFragment();
                xm.remove(l); // remove the node <c>  
            }
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.ROOT);
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);
            long l = vn.getContentFragment();
            xm1.remove(); // remove the node <b>  to save it in a temp file
            xm.output(new FileOutputStream("E://new.xml")); // generate the first file
            xm1.output(new FileOutputStream("E://newonetemp.xml"));
        }
        // prase the temp file
        if (vg.parseFile("e://newonetemp.xml", false)) {
            vn = vg.getNav();
            xm2.bind(vn);
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);

            long l = vn.getContentFragment();
            xm2.remove(); // remove the node <b>
            xm2.output(new FileOutputStream("E://newtwo.xml")); // generate the next file
        }
        if (vg.parseFile("e://test.xml", false)) {
            vn = vg.getNav();

            vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD);

            vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING);

            if (vn.matchElement("d")) {
                long l = vn.getContentFragment();
                String one = vn.toString((int) l, 8); // get the framgment <c></c>
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("e://three.xml");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                bufferedWriter.write(one); // create the last file
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

EDIT : updated condition : xml should have node c

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to manage the DOM. [Reference](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

- some examples:
  [example1](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)
  [example2](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/)
  [example3](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the composite pattern for this. Make XML objects, which can store children XML objects and store the next layer in them.